# Can i use a Java SWT application as an Activex Host?

Tags: java, activex, swt

I know this can be a bit of weird question, but let me explain the idea behind it first.
I have a win32 app exposed a an Activex host, this gives me the the following useful features:

- Embed and call it from Internet Explorer as a simple  to pass/return values from it using javascript.
- Embed and call it from any win32 application made in languages like visual basic, c++, delphi etc. Even i can call it from MS office products like excel and word.

I have been asked to migrate this app to Java SWT but i don´t know if it can be done without losing the mentioned capabilites, the only way could be to expose the app itself as an Activex host, can this be possible?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with ActiveX, but a [lot of examples are in snippets folder](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#ole) at SWT homepage. Try to check them..

Comment: yeah i know, there are a lot of libraries to call com objects from java, but what i need to do is to expose a java app as an Activex class, at this moment i think i can do it for javabeans using the activex bridge, but who knows if this can be done for an entire java app.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrate your app to Java SWT then you will **lose the desired functionality** of using in IE and as well as in other MS product based on COM or ActivX technology. Although one crude way could be to use some bi-directional COM broker like [Jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/).

If given a choice then I will utilize the SWT's in-built support for COM and will try to embed your activex component in my swt application. For example, you can look at:

1. `org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE` **--** Allows access to IE ActiveX component in the form SWT browser control.
2. `org.eclipse.compare.internal.win32.WordComparison` this is a part of eclipse's file diff plugin. The class is very nicely written and gives a COM flavored snippet of diffing two MS word files.

In this way I can have the activex intact for whatever purposes.

There is [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-ActivexSupportInSwt/index.html) article on adding activex support to swt without using any third party COM bridge